# how to select value in comma separated column

Tags: sql

Hi guys in my database the column named "page" values is comma separated how i can detect if my needed value is in there?!

values in column page is: info,start,main,footer,chart

```
$page = "main";
$userPerm = "4";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM perm WHERE page= '".$page."' AND userPerm = '".$userPerm."' ";
$result = $dp->sql_query($sql);
if($row = $dp->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
    return $userPerm;
}else {
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pls tag the DBMS you are using. Also, maybe you got a bad normalized DB, cannot you put each page id in a row? Create a page_perm relational table?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not mandatory or always present, you can't. However you can do this if always present :

```
$string = "Summer is almost done";
$tok = strtok($string, ",");
while ($tok !== false) {
    if ($tok == "summer") {
      do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i found the answer the simple way i must use FIND_IN_SET any way thank you for answer.